# WordPress screen intermittently full of encoded characters

Tags: wordpress, character

A new client’s site occasionally will shown nothing on the screen but these characters. Refreshing can make the normal site reappear or this may show up again, intermittently, when clicking on any page:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0ai7ly1sdmy0kj/image001.jpg?dl=0

Any guidance on what's causing this and how to fix it? The host says they want to move them to a new server, but I don't think that's going to do it...

Comment: Have you set the character like '<meta charset="UTF-8">' in the header?

Comment: Yes: `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`